# Swiz 1.3.1 LogProcessor

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, swiz

i try everything to get the LogProcessor for Swiz to run.
Here are the project [Foomonger](http://blog.foomonger.com/2010/03/20/swizlogger-helpers-swizloggerconfig-and-loggerprocessor/).
I fear however, the ressources refer to an old version of swiz.

I want to implement the LogProceccor without the SwizLoggerConfig, because i need only the possibility to log some informations to thunderbolt. i need no further configuration. After that i start to write my own AbstractSwizLoggingTarget.

If i copy the class into my environment, i get the follow error:
TypeError: Error #1034: Typumwandlung fehlgeschlagen: org.swizframework.utils.logging::SwizLogger@e8aa8b1 kann nicht in mx.logging.ILogger umgewandelt werden.
(Sorry for the german text)

Der Quelltext:

```
package de.axurit.util
{
    import org.swizframework.core.Bean;
    import org.swizframework.processors.BaseMetadataProcessor;
    import org.swizframework.processors.ProcessorPriority;
    import org.swizframework.reflection.IMetadataTag;
    import org.swizframework.utils.logging.SwizLogger;
    
    public class LoggerProcessor extends BaseMetadataProcessor
    {
        
        protected static const LOGGER:String = "Logger";
        
        public function LoggerProcessor()
        {
            super([LOGGER]);
        }
        
        override public function get priority():int
        {
            return ProcessorPriority.INJECT +1;
        }
        
        override public function setUpMetadataTag(metadataTag:IMetadataTag, bean:Bean):void
        {
            var logger:SwizLogger = SwizLogger.getLogger(bean.source);
            bean.source[metadataTag.host.name] = logger; //here occurs the error
        }
        
        override public function tearDownMetadataTag(metadataTag:IMetadataTag, bean:Bean):void
        {
            bean.source[metadataTag.host.name] = null;
        }
        
        
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me how to create an own MetadataProcessor for central logging (not debuggin) in Swiz. I you need more code, let me know that

Thank you
Frank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a long, hard journey. Here is teh result:

```
package de.axurit.util
{
    import org.swizframework.core.Bean;
    import org.swizframework.processors.BaseMetadataProcessor;
    import org.swizframework.reflection.IMetadataTag;
    import org.swizframework.utils.logging.SwizLogger;

    public class LoggerProcessor extends BaseMetadataProcessor
    {
        public function LoggerProcessor()
        {
            super(["Log"]);
        }

        override public function setUpMetadataTag(metadataTag:IMetadataTag, bean:Bean):void
        {
            super.setUpMetadataTag(metadataTag, bean);
            bean.source [metadataTag.host.name] = SwizLogger.getLogger(bean.source);
        }

        override public function tearDownMetadataTag(metadataTag:IMetadataTag, bean:Bean):void
        {
            super.tearDownMetadataTag(metadataTag,bean);
            bean.source[metadataTag.host.name] = null;
        }
    }
}
```